# tinysort doesn't work properly after dynamic loading

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, sorting

I have a very odd issue happening with my wordpress website. My sort functions work fine, then I scroll to the bottom of page, and it loads more posts through infinite scroll(this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/infinite-scroll/), then suddenly my sort functions(tinysort used) starts to act weird, giving me random results. Only happens with new/old and old/new, not with alphabetical sort. This only happens in Chrome, not in firefox or safari.

http://mammalian.ca/newSite/projects/

what is happening? help!!

Answer (score 0):

Strange... your code looks ok... TinySort might be handling the attribute as a string instead of a number. You could try replacing the 'rel' attribute with 'data-time' and sort by data (which looks right if I run it from console):

```
// following commented line is only to test
// $('*[rel]').each(function(i,el){$(el).attr('data-time',$(el).attr('rel'))});
jQuery('div#sortDivs > div').tsort({data:'time',order:'desc'});
```